# How to make an image use it's full width while keeping it's normal height in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Having big problems to fit an image to the screen width while keeping it's normal height. I gather different images from my database (depending on what you clicked previously) and therefor the image height/width are different all the time. How can I make so the image always fills the screen width while keeping it's normal height?

Right now some images fill the width while keeping it's normal height while some images does not.

What I have tried:

`AspectFill` crops out parts of the image so this solution does not work.

`Fill` stretches the image which also is not a good solution.

`theimage.WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth;` I also tried to do this to fix the issue and I get the ScreenWidth from the AppDelegete but theimagedoes not change it's width at all.

I also then tried to add a grid.column like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ColumnDefinition x:Name = "width"/>

</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Image x:Name="theimage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column = "0"  HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "StartAndExpand" />
```

And connecting it in the code like this:

```
width.Width = App.ScreenWidth;
```

But some of the images remains the same and does not fill the screen width.

Do I have to do a custom renderer in order to sucesssfully make an image fill the screens width while keeping it's normal height?

This is the current code I have (that i have changed a million times with the code examples i have above):

```
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" >
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor = "Red" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">

    <Image Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="theimage" Aspect = "AspectFit"  HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" />

    <Button Clicked="clickFunc" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="120" BorderRadius="40" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" />

<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,20,10,0">

    <Label TextColor = "#474747" x:Name="title" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" FontAttributes="Bold" />

</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Grid> 
</StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am running out of ideas to solve this issue now. Do I have to do a renderer in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best option is for you to learn how to use MVVM.(steep but worth the experience)

what you can do is

**View**

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Width="100" Height="{Binding SourceImageHeight,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Image>
```

Using this you can Set the values of Xaml properties inside a ViewModel(class)
which allows your code to be VERY dynamic.

**View Code Behind**(setting the datacontext(can also be set inside the view))

```
InitializeComponent();
viewModel = new YourViewModel();
this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  private String _imageSource = "";

  public String ImageSource
  {
   get{return _imageSource;}
   set{_imageSource = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ImageSource);
      }
  }

  private Int _sourceImageHeight = 0;

  public Int SourceImageHeight 
  {
   get{return _sourceImageHeight ;}
   set{_sourceImageHeight = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SourceImageHeight);
      }
  }
}
```

all you have to do from here is

```
ImageSource = ImageLocation
```

and

```
SourceImageHeight = 1200
```

**Note:** In the Viewmodel, if you dont use the private variables(_imageSource/_sourceImageHeight) and rather use the public Variable name(ImageSource/SourceImageHeight)  in the setter, you will create an Infinite Loop.

Comment: Ok. I will look into it! Thanks! If you know how to do i would very much appreciate some more code in order to see a full solution

Comment: @UnoDosCode I added a bit more :)

Comment: I can't find `NotifyPropertyChanged` I added `using System.ComponentModel;`but then I can online find INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged is part of the Nuget Package SimpleMVVM.
it makes the code alot cleaner.

Comment: Ok adding MvvmLight! What do I need to type in order to add it to my page? `Using _?`

Comment: SimpleMVVM, not MVVMLight

Comment: using SimpleMvvmToolkit;

Comment: Ok, one second.

Comment: Yeah I will. Just having some issues adding the package. I will keep trying give me a bit time

Comment: `Could not install package 'SimpleMvvmToolkit 5.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for sollution ->  Browse -> SimpleMVVMToolkit (Remember to Change Package Source(top right) to All)

Comment: use 5.5.0 (stable version)

Comment: No i cannot find Nuget Package Manager. I am googling but cant figure it out!!

Comment: Your are using Visual Studio correct ?
Nuget package manager comes automatically with all versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using xamarin studio!

Comment: i assumed you are using Visual Studio(xamarin can be used in Visual studio)....well, you can always rely on good old INotifyPropertyChanged....it works just as good, just a tiny bit more code.

Comment: not using NotifyPropertyChanged isnt going to destroy your program.

Comment: Ok, give me some time. I have to go to practice but will resume this when i come home

Comment: @UnoDosCode no problem dude, that's what I'm here for :D